# Twitter Bootstrap required validation not working

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty getting Twitter Bootstraps jqBootstrapValidation.js to work.  I have included the file and I have managed to get the validation working on another input of the form for a regular expression, but the field in the form I am trying to validate at the moment should be simpler : I'm only validating it as a required field.

The HTML is

```
<textarea class="input-xxlarge" id="descTextArea" rows="2"
required="required"
data-validation-required-message="You must complete the description"/>
<p class="help-block">
```

I've also just used required without the "=required"

and for JavaScript I have tried

```
$(#descTextArea).not("focus").jqBootstrapValidation();
```

and a lot of other variations .not("blur") or .on("focusout") or .on("focus") and so on and so on.

The desired behaviour is when the user clicks out of the field and if the field is empty for the validation to fail and for the validation failed message to appear in the help-block.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks (oh and by the way - what does the .not() mean?)  Thanks again.

Linda